# SELECT between n row to n every each group

Tags: sql, oracle

Select `id_student` from each group `id_student` where `id_desireCollage=5` not in first 5 rows student id.

| ID | id_desireCollage | id_student |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 5 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 | 2 |
| 11 | 7 | 2 |
| 12 | 4 | 3 |
| 13 | 3 | 3 |
| 14 | 2 | 3 |
| 15 | 1 | 3 |
| 16 | 8 | 3 |
| 17 | 9 | 3 |
| 18 | 7 | 3 |
| 19 | 5 | 3 |

I tried:

```sql
select id_student
from   student_desire
group by(id_student)
having id_desireCollage not in first 5 rows
```

Expected result is:

| id_student |
| --- |
| 3 |

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example:

```
select id_student
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id_student order by id) as rn 
  from t
) x
where id_desireCollage = 5 and rn > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id_student
FROM   (
  SELECT id_student,
         id_desireCollage,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_student ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM   student_desire
)
WHERE  id_desireCollage = 5
AND    rn > 5;
```

or, from Oracle 12, (without any functions) using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT id_student
FROM   student_desire
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id_student
  ORDER BY id
  PATTERN (^ not5{5,} id5)
  DEFINE
    not5 AS id_desireCollage != 5,
    id5  AS id_desireCollage = 5
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student_desire (ID, id_desireCollage, id_student) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 7, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 4, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 16, 8, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 9, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 18, 7, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 19, 5, 3 FROM DUAL
```

All output:

| ID_STUDENT |
| --- |
| 3 |

---

You can do it without analytic functions or `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, using a correlated sub-query and aggregation functions instead, but its (much) less efficient (and does use the `COUNT` aggregation function):

```sql
SELECT id_student
FROM   student_desire s
WHERE  id <= ( SELECT id
               FROM   student_desire c
               WHERE  s.id_student = c.id_student
               AND    c.id_desireCollage = 5 )
GROUP BY id_student
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hwZpjpsX)

Comment: there way without functions ? @mt0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IDs are sequential within the group, you could query students where the difference between the ID of id_desireCollage=5 and the first id_desireCollage is more than 5:

```sql
SELECT   id_student
FROM     student_desire
GROUP BY id_student
HAVING   MIN(CASE id_desireCollage WHEN 5 THEN id END) - MIN(id) > 5
```